# Container no se ajusta al ancho entero sino al ancho del viewport

Tags: css, estilos

Estoy diseñando una página web para celulares y me encuentro con que los elementos, al centrarse o lo que sea, lo hacen al ancho del viewport y no al ancho de la página. Al tener elementos que sobresalen del ancho del viewport, los elementos centrados quedan mal centrados, y la barra de navegación se muestra bien solo en la parte del viewport, cuando se scrollea horizontalmente, la misma se corta. Como puedo hacer? Ya que no puedo evitar que esos elementos sean más "chicos" de lo que ya son. Muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Adjunto un ejemplo de lo que me refiero:

[image]

Esta es la página hasta el viewport sin scrollear

Y esta es la página cuando se scrollea horizontalmente:

[image]

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no, 
    user-scalable=0">

    {% load static %}
    
    <!-- Icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'img/univac-logo.ico' %}"/>

    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-grid.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-grid.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-reboot.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/toggler_styles.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom_styles.css' %}">
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    
    <!-- Main JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootrstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/alerts.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery-validate-1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery-validate-1.19.1/localization/messages_es_AR.min.js' %}"></script>

    <title>Univ@c  |  {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarsExample03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="brand brand-name">
        <a class="navbar-brand ml-auto" href="{% url 'home' %}">
          <img src="{% static 'img/univac-logo.bmp' %}" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
          Univ@c
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item {% if '/clientes/' in request.path %} active {% endif %}" >
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'clientes' %}">Clientes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item {% if '/cuentas_corrientes/' in request.path %} active {% endif %}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cuentas_corrientes' %}">Cuentas corrientes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item {% if '/articulos/' in request.path %} active {% endif %}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'articulos' %}">Articulos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item {% if '/pedidos/' in request.path %} active {% endif %}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'pedidos' %}">Pedidos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Salir</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      {% block boton %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="head">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {  
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: auto;
}

nav{
  background-color: #0d88fc;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Hola ,  te recomiendo ver la página [ask] para leer un poco más acerca de como realizar preguntas y así puedas ayudarnos a ayudarte. Sería util que agregaras el código que genera dicho problema para poder analizarlo.

Comment: Hola, el tema es que no hay código que genere el problema o al menos no se cual es. Yo supongo que es el mismo bootstrap el que hace eso, pero es una suposición.

Comment: Podrías agregar la sección de codigo con la que generas la tabla, tanto HTML, como CSS. Esto daría una idea de como se crea y poder encontrar una solución.

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá el problema lo esta generando la `tabla`, lo tenes que hacer `responsive` a la `tabla`, si estas usando `Bootstrap 4.0` te recomiendo que lo insertes así a la `tabla`...

```
<div class="table-responsive"> <!--Este contenedor hace responsive a tu tabla -->
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Sos un genio!!!!! Me re contra sirvio! Muchisimas gracias!!